# Контейнер бинарное дерево

Tags: бинарное-дерево, c++

Нужно реализовать простейший контейнер для бинарного дерева, определить функции begin(), end() и перегрузить для итератора операторы ++ и *. Для перемещения по элементам решил узлы дерева записывать в STL-list и уже по нему двигать итератор. Самый крайний левый элемент дерева считается началом контейнера, элемент за крайним правым - конец контейнера.

```
template <typename T>
    class Node
    {
     private:
        T data;
        Node<T> *left, *right;
        bool flag;
        friend class Tree<T>;
     public:
        Node(): flag(false), left(NULL), right(NULL){}
        ~Node(){if(left){delete left; left = NULL;}
                if(right){delete right; right = NULL;}}
    };

    template <typename T>
    class Tree
    {
    private:
        friend class Iterator;
        Node<T>* head;
    public:
        class Iterator
        {
         private:
            list<Node<T> > li;
            typename std::list<Node<T> >::iterator li_it;
            void build(Node<T>*);
         public:
            Iterator();
            ~Iterator();
            Iterator(const Iterator&);
            Iterator& operator ++ ();
            T& operator * ();
        };
```

Проблема в том, что если  в дереве происходят изменения (добавили/удалили узел), то весь list придется перестраивать. То есть я должен в любой момент времени иметь доступ к самому дереву ну или к его корню. Что можно предпринять в этом случае?

Comment: Прикольная реализация итератора, который занимает `O(N)` памяти для дерева из `N` элементов. Попробуйте его покопировать где-нибудь в `performance-critical` участке кода.

Comment: Я согласен, что итератором такое назвать нельзя. Да и дерево как таковое контейнером сложно представить наподобие STL. Но как можно реализовать тогда хотя бы подобие итератора в моем случае?

Comment: Добавьте в Node к Left, Right еще и Parent (ссылка на родителя, для корня NULL).

Соответственно придется изменить методы вставки и удаления узлов, но обход (количество данных в итераторе) упростится.

Comment: @carapuz Посмотрите, как сделаны итераторы в `STL`-подобных `tree` контейнерах. В качестве хорошего референса могу предложить вам **[описание итераторов `tree.hh`.][1]**

[1]: http://tree.phi-sci.com/tree.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Если вы осуществляете доступ к узлам дерева через итератор, то такое вполне возможно. После удаления одного объекта из контейнера, в большинстве случаев все итераторы становятся невалидными. И в связи с этим, дерево приходится перестраивать.

Comment: то есть мне нужно для выполнения скажем  одного прохождения создать итератор, отработать с ним и потом удалить. а для следующей операции - создавать новый итератор, если дерево изменялось? или все-таки можно как-то изменять существующий итератор?

Comment: @carapuz, IMHO итератор **должен всегда** отслеживать актуальное состояние объекта. По крайней мере он **не должен** ссылаться на удаленные элементы коллекции.

К сожалению, далеко все все слеуют такой модели.

Comment: @avp: С этим реально сложно, потому что итератор существует отдельно от контейнера, и контейнер не знает, когда итератор ещё жив, а когда уже уничтожен, потому что больше не нужен клиенту. Поэтому контейнер не может сообщить итератору о том, что он изменил структуру. STL-овские итераторы просто перестают быть валидными после любого изменения контейнера, и это их официальная архитектура. (Некропостинг, да.)

Comment: @VladD, да, сложно. Поэтому и ошибок с ними много (программист же *верит*, что ему предоставили *правильный* инструмент, а то про что он на самом деле  ущербный, редко кто говорит).

Comment: @avp: Хрестоматийный пример leaky abstraction, как на мой вкус. Поэтому и возникают вопросы «а как удалить из контейнера во время итерации по нему». Ошибка проектирования, одним словом.